# Explain a quote from "The Great Wall of China" by Franz Kafka

Tags: meaning, short-stories, german-language, franz-kafka

Can anyone explain the following quote from the short story "The Great Wall of China" by Franz Kafka:

> First, one must realize that at that time certain achievements were brought to fruition which rank only slightly behind the Tower of Babel, although in the pleasure they gave to God, at least by human reckoning, they made an impression exactly the opposite of that structure.

Comment: For context, you should realize that God did not approve of the Tower of Babel.